# Using Laravel's Seeding to seed coordinates with ST_GEOMFROMTEXT, leads to error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-seeding

I am trying to make seeder file which seeds my table. But the problem is that one field is a type of POLYGON and according to SQL I gotta use the ST_GEOMFROMTEXT to insert coordinates.

The query I am trying to do without seeding works perfectly with just SQL

So I am trying like this:

```
ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((27.35321 57.515823,27.279053 57.53499399999998,27.349091 57.533151,27.352524 57.51637600000001,27.35321 57.515823))')
```

But this leads me to error:

> Numeric value out of range: 1416 Cannot get geometry object from data
>   you send to the GEOMETRY field

This is the function:

```
public function run(){
        DB::table('country')->insert([
            'polygon' => "ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((27.35321 57.515823,27.279053 57.53499399999998,27.349091 57.533151,27.352524 57.51637600000001,27.35321 57.515823))')"
        ]);
}
```

As you can see from the coordinates, then the starting point and the end point is the same. Also the syntax is correct. So I do not know, what I am doing wrong. Can anyone lead me to the right track?

Comment: Have you tried DB::raw?

Comment: @Tschallacka ohh, that was the thing I didn't try. I just did it and it worked. Thank you very much. Too much work is not good.

Comment: Is there any other way then DB::raw?

Comment: @SaquibLari you could use a thing like https://github.com/njbarrett/laravel-postgis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using DB::raw() for things not listed under https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#adding-columns

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#running-queries

Please keep in mind it will limit your app to a specific database engine that accepts that syntax.

Ideally you'd extend the grammar with your type and modify it for all the database engines your app might run on/tested on like sqlite for unit tests.